# How to replace id's with same value in a large data set

Tags: r

I have a large data set 513 observation in total. one of the column in the data set relates to ID.

However, in my data set I have one ID repeating (For eg 1). `Id1 = 1756, Id2 = 1756`.

How do I correct this and just separate the two ID's without touching the other rows/columns and values of the data set. I have tried using this:

```
        Initial_df[nrow(Initial_df$sofifa_id) +1, 1:17] = c('1757', '230204', 
    '71', '9000', '26', '182', '65', 'KV Kortrijk', 'Right', '85', '66', 
'65', '71', '54', '57', '52', '69', '1' )
```

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Correct it how? Is it actually a unique case that just needs a different ID? Is it a duplicate that needs to be removed?

Comment: Yes but thank you for your reply, I have figured it out